# get npm process exitcode as output in powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I'm new to Powershell and want to automate some process by Powershell script.
Is there any way to get the status of npm run build, if it fails. Currently, if I'm not adding a condition then it sequencely runs the next commands either its success or fails.

I already added `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` but it only works for cmdlet.

```
$exitcode = npm run build
#need exitcode as output to check
if ($exitcode -eq 0) {
   Remove-Item -Path $spaNodeModulePath -Force -Recurse
   mkdir $spaNodeModulePath
   xcopy $libDistPath $spaNodeModulePath /e
   Set-Location $spaPath
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$LASTEXITCODE` variable which contains the [exit code of the last native program that was run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#lastexitcode). So first execute the program and check the `$LASTEXITCODE` later.

```
npm run build 
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "NPM build was successful"
}
```

Please note that `$LASTEXITCODE` is not something that user defines, It's [created and maintained by the PowerShell runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#short-description).